# Overriding object value in loop in scala

Tags: scala, performance, loops, gatling, scala-gatling

im trying to write some generic test scenario builders for gatling and my problem is that I have a list of objects, and I want to iterate over it and do something with every object.

So i do like this

```
var counter = 0
   val scn = scenario("scenario")
      .repeat(requestsList.requests.size) {
        var tmp = requestLists.requests(counter)
                 ....
counter += 1
}
```

but when I printing tmp object it always show the first object from list and dosen't get second one. What im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the gatling DSL creates immutable builders that are only executed once - so your looping / array indexing approach won't work

you'll have to use gatling's feeder constructs

Comment: Yeah I was feeling like that might be the case, and way I didn't know that is possible through feeder. For this I should create a loop with indexer, and indicate it in my feeder? Anyway thank you for response! :)

Comment: once your datasource is in a feeder, you can use the looping DSL commands like .repeat (whith .feed being called at the start of the loop)

Comment: an alternative is to use one of the loop variants that gives access to the counter as a session variable - you can then use that value to index into your array